# How to Parse XML using SAX parser in BlackBerry?

Tags: xml, blackberry, saxparser

I don't know how to parse XML.

Comment: sax is an update type of parsing. Are you open to other types of parsers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See RIM's documentation: "[How To - Use the XML Parser](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800599/How_To_-_Use_the_XML_Parser.html?nodeid=820554&vernum=0)". It clearly describes how to do this.

Comment: Thanks bhakki But u have any referenced link using SAXParsing

Comment: May be this [link](http://jsinghfoss.wordpress.com/2009/09/06/sax-parsing-revising/) helps you